# How to avoid clone() boilerplate code for polymorphic objects in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

If I want to clone a polymorphic object in C++ (i.e. an instance of a class A which is derived from some other class B), the easiest way seems to give B a virtual clone member function, that has to be overridden by A and looks like this

```
A* clone(){
    return new A(*this);
}
```

My problem is, that I find this unnecessary boilerplate code, as this is almost always needed, if one wants to use run-time polymorphic features of C++. How can it be circumvented?

Thanks

**Why I need this:**

My use case can be abstracted to the following example:
I have a `class Integral`, which evaluates the integral of some function. Do do this, they have a member which is a pointer to the `class MathFunction`. This abstract class contains a pure virtual function `evaluate` which takes one argument. I I wanted to implement the power function I would create a `class PowFunction : class MathFunction`. This class would have a member `exponent` and the function evaluate would look like this:

```
double evaluate(x){
    return pow(x,exponent);
}
```

As stated the member `MathFunction` of `class Integral` has to be polymorhpic, which requires it to be a pointer. To answer the questions of the commenters with another question. Why wouldn't I want to be able to make copies of MathFunction objects?

I really want the Integral to "own" its MathFunction, meaning, that it can alter the parameters (like `exponent`) without changing the MathFunction of any other Integral object. This means every Integral needs to have its own copy. This requires a clone() function for MathFunctions, doesn't it?

One alternative i thought of: If several Integral objects can share the same MathFunction via a pointer to the same address, I could create copies of Integral objects without the need to copy the MathFunction. But in this case I would have to make all the properties const or somehow readonly, which is not very elegant either. Also, which Integral object should handle delete the MathFunction object?

**Why you need this:**

Are you seriously saying, that as soon as you work with polymorphic objects you don't ever need a copy operation? What makes polymorphic object different from other objects in this respect?

Using this argumentation, you could also throw the copy constructor and copy assignment operator out of the C++ standard!

Comment: Actually this is almost never needed. You should provide clone functions only if you really need them.

Comment: What is your use case. This is very rare in C++.

Comment: I've been using the run-time polymorphic features of C++ for well over ten years now.  I don't think I've written a virtual `.clone()` function.  What are you doing that you need this?

Comment: What _run-time polymorphic feature of C++_ requires you to allocate a new object? Implement your interface and usage of derived polymorphic objects in terms of base class pointers and this should be unnecessary.

Comment: Imagine you have a pointer-to-a-base-class, and you want to call a non-const virtual method on the referenced object....  but you know the object might also be referenced by some other code (possibly even in another thread), and you don't want your changes to be visible to that other code.  In that case it would be handy to make a local copy of the object first, so you can modify only your local copy instead of messing up the shared copy.  In that case a clone() method is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handled this issue with a macro... it's ugly, but it works to avoid inconsistencies.

```
/** An interface that can be inherited by any class that wants to provide a Clone()
  * method that will return a copy of itself.
  */
class ICloneable
{
public:
   ICloneable() {}
   virtual ~ICloneable() {}

   virtual ICloneable * Clone() const = 0;
};
#define DECLARE_STANDARD_CLONE_METHOD(class_name) virtual ICloneable * Clone() const {new class_name(*this);}

[...]
public MyCloneableClass : public ICloneable
{
public:
   MyCloneableClass() {}

   DECLARE_STANDARD_CLONE_METHOD(MyCloneableClass);
};
```

Comment: I like this approach, because I think, C++ is missing this feature and thus we are forced to use ugly macros. I find the alternative (to write boilerplate code ourselfs, instead of the preprocessor) even worse.!

Answer (score 9):

Reduce the need to clone polymorphic objects. Really, I rarely find the need for this in my own code, and the comments on the question suggest that I'm hardly alone in the opinion that if you find yourself cloning everything, you're probably designing it wrong.

Of course, never to be unhelpful, you could indeed use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

```
template<typename T> struct Clone {
    virtual T* clone() { return new T(static_cast<const T&>(*this)); }
};
```

Comment: I think there was a problem with the CRTP approach, as the derived type is not fully defined when the CRTP base is instantiated, but I need to look for the link...

Comment: @Xeo : There's a fundamental difference between instantiating the base and instantiating member functions of the base. This code should be fine, as the derived class should be a complete type by the time `Clone::clone` is instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Don't you have to cast the pointer and not the object itself? (i.e. `return new T(*(static_cast<T*>(this)));`?

Comment: And is there a way to use this approach with abstract classes? The problem is: If my base class is abstract, then I cannot inherit from `Clone`, because the `new T` will produce an error for an abstract T:"cannot instantiate abstract class"

Comment: @user578832 : Use of `static_cast` in this manner is well defined -- it's not casting the object, it's casting a reference to the object, which behaves more-or-less identically to casting a pointer to the object.

Comment: This does not work. E.g.: `class A:public Clone<A>` and `class B:public A,public Clone<B>` and `A* b=new B`then `b.clone()` will produce a new `A`?!!!

Comment: Does boost have a utility on these lines for cloning?

Comment: I am not sure why people are saying that clone is rarely needed. I have to copy a Composite object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). How can I achieve it without clone-ing?

Comment: @phaedrus: The fact that you implemented that pattern as inheritance and not templates is irrelevant to the pattern itself.

Comment: @user578832: In the case of MI, you will have to `using` the correct implementation.